# Derived address different from CLI to NodeJS

Tags: bitcoind, bip32-hd-wallets, node.js

Basically I'm trying to create a system in which each user has it's own address to deposit on the site, however I'm having issues with monitoring addresses as they appear to be different results within CLI & Node.

Here's the code used to import the private key based on derived user ID:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

const hdNode = bitcoinjs.bip32.fromBase58(config.BIP32_DERIVED_PRIVATE, bitcoinjs.networks.bitcoin);

exec('bitcoin-cli importprivkey "' + hdNode.derive(user.id).toWIF() + '" "' + email + '" false');
```

Okay, now for the user side of things, the derived key is displayed using the following:

```
var derivedPubKey = config.BIP32_DERIVED;
if (!derivedPubKey)
    throw new Error('Must set env var BIP32_DERIVED_KEY');

const hdNode = bitcoinjs.bip32.fromBase58(derivedPubKey, bitcoinjs.networks.bitcoin);

exports.deriveAddress = function(index) {
    return bitcoinjs.payments.p2pkh({
        pubkey: hdNode.derive(index).publicKey,
        network: bitcoinjs.networks.bitcoin
    }).address;
};
```

However both results appear to be completely different? if I type `bitcoin-cli listreceivedbyaddress 1 true` into my SSH I get the following result:
[image]

But then for this same account, on the user interface I get the following:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

`bitcoin-cli` is generating a P2WPKH address (`bc1...`), but then on the user side you are generating a P2PKH address (`1....`).

You may also need to check to ensure the same address derivation path is being used (Bitcoin-core uses hardened derivation).

For more info on address encodings see:

[What is P2PK, P2PKH, P2SH, P2WPKH - ELI5](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/64733/what-is-p2pk-p2pkh-p2sh-p2wpkh-eli5)

[What is the size of different Bitcoin transaction types?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/66428/what-is-the-size-of-different-bitcoin-transaction-types/75124#75124)